# Remove a task folder using schtasks.exe

Tags: batch-file, cmd, task, windows-task-scheduler

In my program, after installing, I'm adding a task to the task scheduler using the following command :

```
schtasks.exe /create /xml "task.xml" /tn "MyTasks/Task1" /f
```

In order to properly uninstall the program, I want to be able to remove totally the task folder "MyTasks".
I can selectively delete this task using this command, but the folder still exists in the end :

```
schtasks.exe /delete /tn "MyTasks/Task1" /f
```

Is there a way to completely delete the folder ?

Thanks !

Comment: `schtasks.exe /delete /tn "MyTasks\Task1" /f`[`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)[`rd`](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html)`"MyTasks"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do this, but not using `schtasks`: `schtasks` is able to create a directory, if asked for, but when using `schtasks` it can delete a task entry within a directory, but it can't delete the directory itself. I can only advise you to find the directory on your computer and to perform an `rmdir`.

Comment: Where is the physical folder for scheduled tasks? To use `rd` or `rmdir` wouldn't a physical folder be required?

Comment: @NekoMusume Scheduled Tasks have been stored in different places over the years including the registry. The first scheduler is `at` (type `at /?` for help). These are upgraded to the current version when you upgrade Windows. Win 95 had System Agent and Task Scheduler 1 came in with Win 98 (auto upgrading System Agent tasks). Currently the tasks are XML files at `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a vbs file.

```
Set TS  = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
TS.Connect("ComputerName")
Set RootFolder = TS.GetFolder("\")
RootFolder.DeleteFolder "MyTasks", 0
```

Substitute your computer name.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/taskfolder-deletefolder

Comment: Scripting it seems to be the only way. Deleting the task folder in C:\Windows\System32\Tasks as suggested in the other answers does not remove the folder within Task Scheduler. A PowerShell variant would be `$TS = New-Object -Com Schedule.Service; $TS.Connect("$($env:ComputerName)"); $RootFolder = $TS.GetFolder("\"); $RootFolder.DeleteFolder("MyTasks", 0)`